Law of the unconscious statistician for conditional density
According to this answer, the law of the unconscious statistician implies
$$E[h(X) \mid Z=z]=\int h(x) g(x\mid z) ~\mathrm{d}x.$$
But what about
$$E[h(X \mid Y) \mid Z=z]?$$
Is it true that
$$E[h(X \mid Y) \mid Z=z] = \int h(x \mid y) g(x\mid z) ~\mathrm{d}x?$$
The reason I am asking this is because I am currently studying conditional score functions, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\log h_{Y \mid X, \mathrm{B}}(y \mid x, \beta)$, which should have mean zero when evaluated at the true value of the associated parameter $\beta^*$.
Edit: Here's more information about the role of $y$ and $z$. Under some regularity conditions, the law of the unconscious statistician implies that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    E\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta) \mid \Theta = \theta^* \right] 
    &= \int \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \log f_{X \mid \Theta} (x \mid \theta)\right) f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta^*) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
    &= \int \frac{\partial f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta)}{\partial \theta}\frac{1}{f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta)}f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta^*) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
$$ E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta^*) \mid \Theta = \theta^*\right] = \int \frac{\partial f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta^*)}{\partial \theta} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int f_{X \mid \Theta}(x \mid \theta^*) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} [1] =0. $$
Now I'm trying to show that
$$E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log g_{Y \mid \mathbf{X}, \Theta}(y \mid \mathbf{x}, \theta^*) \mid \Theta = \theta^*\right] = 0,$$
where $g_{Y \mid \mathbf{X}, \Theta}(y \mid \mathbf{x}, \theta^*)$ is some likelihood function corresponding to a regression of $y$ on $\mathbf{x}$.

Whats $y$? What is its relation to $z$?

@Firebug thank you! I just edited the question to give some context. Note that the role of $y$ and $x$ are interchanged and $z$ becomes $\theta$.

Your conditional expectation is presently ambiguous, since it's not clear if you want the expectation taken over both random variables $X$ and $Y$ (yielding a constant) or if you want the expectation only over $X$ (yielding a random variable that is a function of $Y$).  In the first case the correct rule is:
$$\mathbb{E}_{X,Y|Z}[(h(X|Y))| Z=z]
= \int h(x|y) g(x,y|z) \ dx \ dy,$$
and in the second case it is:
$$\mathbb{E}_{X|Z}[(h(X|Y))| Z=z]
= \int h(x|Y) g(x|z) \ dx.$$
(Your expression is incorrect in either case, since it yields a function of $y$, which does not even appear on the left-hand-side.)

thank you! I think I am confused as to what expectation I am taking myself. I just edited my question to give some additional context. Given that likelihood function I described, I supposed I would be dealing with an expectation with respect to $Y \mid \Theta$? What do I regard $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log g_{Y \mid \mathbf{X}, \Theta}(y \mid \mathbf{x}, \theta^*)$ as a function of?
